# Increase ProgressBar with each string.replacement

Tags: xml, string, vb.net, replace, progress-bar

I have a simple piece of code that converts a full XML file to string.

```
     xOrgXml.Load(mOrgFile)
     fFullString = xOrgXml.OuterXml
```

I use string.replace to replace certain parts of the string with input from another Form. Afterwards I convert it back to a full XML file. This is all working fine.

```
    fFullString = fFullString.Replace("<XMLtag>Item</XMLtag>", "<XMLtag>" & Form2.NewItem & "</XMLtag>")
    mXMLDocSave.LoadXml(fFullString)
    mXMLDocSave.Save(pSavelocation)
```

Because "Item" is present multiple times in the string I want to increase the progress bar with (1) each time a replacement is done but the string.replace method is a one time pass over even when enclosing it in a For Each statement.

```
    fFullString = fFullString.Replace("<XMLtag>Item</XMLtag>", "<XMLtag>" & Form2.NewItem & "</XMLtag>")
    pProgressbar.Increment(1)
```

I have tried to split up the full string using string.split but this is not working for me because the only Chars available for splitting are "<" and ">" which are key parts of the XML tags needed when converting the string back to a XML file

Does anyone have a solid idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Maybe create a loop that checks for the IndexOf your string and each time it finds it, it replaces just one instance at a time using Substring

Comment: Thanks for your comment Chase, I haven't explored the IndexOf option as I have found another solution already but maybe using the IndexOf could result in a cleaner code. Maybe post a sample code as secondary answer for others facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical I post a question and 30 minutes later I find a solution...

For future reference if someone is facing for a similar challenge:

I changed my string.replace statement to a replace statement which only replaces the first match its encounters. Enclosing this in a For Each combined with a Do Until loop the progress bar increases by (1) each time.

Original string.replace:

```
    fFullString = fFullString.Replace("<XMLtag>Item</XMLtag>", "<XMLtag>" & Form2.NewItem & "</XMLtag>")
```

New string replace with limitation on 1 (....., , **1**) enclosed in For Each and Do Until loop:

```
For Each Replacement As String In ReplaceCollection
    If Replacement = "<XMLtag>Item</XMLtag>" Then
          Do Until fFullString.Contains(Replacement) = False
               fFullString = Replace(fFullString, Replacement, "<XMLtag>" & Form2.NewItem & "</XMLtag>", , 1)
               pProgressbar.Increment(1)
          Loop
    End If
Next
```

I hope this will help others also.

Comment: Yes, that's a similar concept to what I was suggesting, in fact, I prefer your solution over mine because it encapsulates the check for one instance and replace into one line.